# Is it possible to open a dialog or go to a new page based on the value of an object using just one button?

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to use a single "create" button that either opens a dialog or goes to a new page using ui-router, depending on the value of an object.

I'm not sure of the best way to accomplish this, I have something that seems to work, but I'm wondering if there's a better way. I'm currently using two buttons and an ng-if to hide the button I don't need at the time, but that seems messy to me.

Here's a very simple mock up of what I'm trying to do. Rather than actually opening a dialog or changing page content, I've just added alerts.

http://codepen.io/jwelker9/pen/QNPgyE?editors=1010

In short, I'm not sure how to get ui-sref and a dialog to play together on the same button.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller = "lists-detail" ng-app="app">

  <table class="listing">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Item-Id:</th>
        <th>Ordinal:</th>
        <th>Type:</th>
        <th>Content-Id:</th>
        <th>
          <button ng-if="!boolean"
              class="button"
              aria-label="Add list item"
              ui-sref="site.lists">
            Add New
          </button>

          <button ng-if="boolean"
              class="button"
              aria-label="Add list item"
              ng-click="dialog()">
            Add New
          </button>

        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('lists-detail', function ($scope) {


  //actual code looks like: 
  //This calls an API to determine if it is correct type or not
  //If boolean is true, it should open a new dialog 
  //if(listType == 'Episode'){
      $scope.boolean = false;
  //}  

  $scope.goToNewPage = function() {
    alert("NewPage");
  }

  $scope.dialog = function() {
    alert("Open Dialog");
  }
})
```

Comment: you have to use $route to go to another page or you can change $location object(window.location.href) by code

Comment: Yes, normally I use ui-router to go to the new page. I just don't have it in this code for simplicity's sake. The problem is I'm not sure how to make a single button work in order to accommodate either opening a dialog or using a ui-router, depending on the value of $scope.boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you could just call a function when the value changes and make the decision in the function like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/tma739u9/

### Angular

```
vm.boolean = false;
vm.watchBoolean = function() {
    var decision = (!vm.boolean) ? newPage() : dialog();
}

function newPage() {
    $location.path('/page');
}

function dialog() {
    alert('Open dialog');
}
```

### HTML

```
 <input
  type="checkbox"
  ng-model="ctrl.boolean"
  ng-click="ctrl.watchBoolean()"> Click Me
```

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in my question, this would work perfect; however I'm using ui-router to direct the user to the new page. I've updated my code to show this. Is there a way to evaluate, as you've done up above, but using router instead of newPage() as a ng-click??

Comment: You could inject $location as a dependency and in your newPage function you could use $location.path('somepage'). That will route to a new page.

Comment: So instead of using ui-sref=" myPage", leave it as an ng-click evaluated using $location? I hadn't considered that, but seems solid. Will that affect the flow of ui-router to and from that create page?  Using $location instead of ui-sref?

Comment: Updated my answer, but yes, $location.path() will just route to whatever page you add as the path parameter.

Comment: Works just like I needed! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

In your `ng-click`, you can use an Angular expression like this:

```
ng-click="boolean==true? dialog() : gotoNewPage()"
```

This is a shorthand way of saying this in Javascript:

```
if (boolean) {
    dialog();
} else {
    gotoNewPage();
}
```